# _main already defined in file.obj

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am reading a book which teaches assembly using MASM via Visual C++ Express.

The book gives the following example program to test that masm is working

```
    .386
    .model flat, c
    .stack 100h
printf PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
    .data
msg1fmt byte "%s%d",0Ah,0
msg1 byte "The answer is: ",0
num1 sdword ?
num2 sdword ?
    .code
main proc
    mov num1,5
    mov eax,num1
    mov num2,eax
    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1fmt, ADDR msg1, num2
    ret
main endp
    end
```

I then get the error error **LNK2005: _main already defined in asm.obj**

I am using the sample assembly program from my book so hopefully it is not in error. The error I get seems to have something to do with main being listed twice, but I'm unsure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not unheard of at all for programming examples in books to be in error.

Note that the error you're getting is from the *linker*, not the *assembler*. The fact you're getting that far already shows that the assembler is happy with your file, and indeed your assembly file defines `main` only once.

I'm not familiar with the MS development tools, especially not ones from the last decade and a half, but I imagine that either you have added a C or C++ module to your project that defines `main()` as a function in that language, or that the IDE is "helpfully" providing a default definition. It is this second definition of `main` that the linker is unhappy about.

(The underscore in symbol in the linker's error message is just an artifact of how you do things on that platform - all HLL symbols get prefixed by an underscore. I note you have `.model flat, c` - that may be telling MASM to prefix symbols despite assembly not being a high-level language.)

You could try looking for the definition of `main()` in the C-land part of your project and simply deleting it or omitting it from the project, if you can find it. Failing that, rename your assembly function to, say, `asm_main`, and then calling *that* from C-land:

```
int main() {
  return asm_main();
}
```

(This is just to get you going; if you want to get hold of `argc` et al, you'll need to get more creative.)

Comment: It was indeed the default c++ file included in my project. Excluding that solved my problem.